# Dynamically import modules for use in lambda expression

Tags: python, lambda, import

I need to dynamically create a function from a lambda expression that is provided as a string (it will be read from a configuration file). I want to allow the user to also specify a list of modules that can then be used within the lambda expression. For this I need to dynamically load the modules and make them available so that they can be referred to by name within the lambda expression.

The following is a possible implementation of what I want to do:

```py
import importlib

def create_function(lambda_expression, modules=[]):
    for module in modules:
        globals()[module] = importlib.import_module(module)
    function = eval('lambda ' + lambda_expression)
    return function
```

It would be used like this:

```py
f = create_function('x: numpy.clip(x, 0, 1)', ['numpy'])
```

However, the use of `globals()` does not seem like a nice solution. Is there a more elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: can you setup your configuration file differently, like as actual code, and then import the module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Python's `eval` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) accepts a `globals` argument. So you can do something like this:

```
function = eval('lambda ' + lambda_expression, lambda_globals)
```

Comment: This works well and looks like a perfect solution for my task. Thanks.